# problem with write from spark structured streaming to oracle table

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I read files in a directory with readStream and process files, at the end I have a dataframe that I want to write it to oracle table. I use jdbc driver for do that and foreachbach() api.here my code:

```
def SaveToOracle(df,epoch_id):
try:
    df.write.format('jdbc').options(
          url='jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.49.8:1521:ORCL',
          driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
          dbtable='spark.result_table',
          user='spark',
          password='spark').mode('append').save()
    pass
except Exception as e:
    response = e.__str__()
    print(response)

streamingQuery = (summaryDF4.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch(SaveToOracle)
  .start()
                 )
```

the job fail without any error and stop after start query streaming. the console log is like this:

```
2021-08-11 10:45:11,003 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
2021-08-11 10:45:11,003 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
2021-08-11 10:45:11,007 INFO streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
2021-08-11 10:45:11,009 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: YARN client scheduler backend Stopped
2021-08-11 10:45:11,011 INFO streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {}
2021-08-11 10:45:11,021 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2021-08-11 10:45:11,034 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
2021-08-11 10:45:11,034 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
2021-08-11 10:45:11,042 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
2021-08-11 10:45:11,046 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2021-08-11 10:45:11,053 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
2021-08-11 10:45:11,056 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
2021-08-11 10:45:11,056 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bf5c7539-9d1f-4c9d-af46-0c0874a81a40/pyspark-7416fc8a-18bd-4e79-aa0f-ea673e7c5cd8
2021-08-11 10:45:11,060 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-47c28d1d-236c-4b64-bc66-d07a918abe01
2021-08-11 10:45:11,063 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bf5c7539-9d1f-4c9d-af46-0c0874a81a40
2021-08-11 10:45:11,065 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/temporary-f9420356-164a-4806-abb2-f132b8026b20
```

what is the problem and how can I get a proper log?
this is my sparkSession conf:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.jars", "/home/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar")

spark=(SparkSession
       .builder
       .config(conf=conf)
       .master("yarn")
       .appName("Test010")
       .getOrCreate()
      )
```

Update:

I get Error on jdbc save(), here is :

```
An error occurred while calling o379.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call awaitTermination() method on streamingQuery after start() method call like this:

```
streamingQuery = (summaryDF4.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch(SaveToOracle)
  .start()
  .awaitTermination())
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer it keeps streaming job alive but still it doesn't work

```
  "id" : "3dc2a37f-4a7a-49b9-aa83-bff526aa14c5",
  "runId" : "e8864901-2729-41c5-b7e4-a19ac2478f1c",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2021-08-11T06:51:00.000Z",
  "batchId" : 2,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 240,
    "getBatch" : 66,
    "latestOffset" : 21,
    "queryPlanning" : 143,
    "triggerExecution" : 514,
    "walCommit" : 23
  },
  "eventTime" : {
    "watermark" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ {
    "numRowsTotal" : 0,
    "numRowsUpdated" : 0,
    "memoryUsedBytes" : -1,
    "numRowsDroppedByWatermark" : 0,
    "customMetrics" : {
      "loadedMapCacheHitCount" : 0,
      "loadedMapCacheMissCount" : 0,
      "stateOnCurrentVersionSizeBytes" : -1
    }
  } ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "FileStreamSource[hdfs://192.168.49.13:9000/input/lz]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "logOffset" : 1
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "logOffset" : 2
    },
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "ForeachBatchSink",
    "numOutputRows" : -1
  }
}
```

if I use console my process doesn't have any problem and it will be correct but for write to oracle I have problem.

Comment: You should add this to your original post as update, don't add in answer section or add as a comment to my answer.